# How do I extend a RAID5 array with storcli?

Tags: raid5, lsi, megaraid, storcli

I just bought a new disk. How do I extend an existing RAID array without losing data?

Answer (score 10):

**If you make a mistake, you can lose all your data. Backup first. Then continue.**

Use `storcli /c0 show` to see what drives and volumes you have. The `TOPOLOGY` table is a good start:

```
TOPOLOGY :
========

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  10.914 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  10.914 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   0   252:0    10  DRIVE Onln  N   2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   1   252:1    9   DRIVE Onln  N   2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   2   252:2    11  DRIVE Onln  N   2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   3   252:3    8   DRIVE Onln  N   2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   4   252:4    12  DRIVE Onln  N   2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This shows you which disks are already in the RAID array. I only have a single RAID array (`Arr`) with the ID `0`.

`PD LIST` shows you the disks:

```
PD LIST :
=======

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    10 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:1     9 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:2    11 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:3     8 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:4    12 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:6    14 GHS    - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 D  -    
252:7    13 UGood  - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 D  -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The newly added disk should show up as `UGood` (unconfigured good). In the example, that's the disk `13` in slot `7` of enclosure `252`.

To add the disk to the RAID array:

```
storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid5 option=add drives=252:13
```

`/c0` is the controller, `/v0` is the RAID volume (see `TOPOLOGY` above or `VD LIST`) to change, `start migrate` is the command to issue, `type=raid5` means "keep it RAID5", we want to add a disk (`option=add`) and `drives` is the list of disks to add in the form `EID:Slt` (see `PD LIST`).

The process can take several days. You can continue to use the file system(s) on the RAID volume while the controller does the work in the background. You can even reboot the server, the controller will just continue from where it was.

To check the progress, use `storcli /c0/v0 show migrate` which will print something like:

```
VD Operation Status :
===================

-----------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Progress% Status          Estimated Time Left 
-----------------------------------------------------------
 0 Migrate          38 In Progress     49 Minutes                   
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: The estimation is way off; those 49 minutes were 3 hours in my case. My feeling is that that first estimation of 2 days 8 hours was way more accurate.

When the migration is finished, the controller will do another background job ("background initialization"). Not sure what that is.

When it's done, it will print:

```
VD Operation Status :
===================

-----------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Progress% Status          Estimated Time Left 
-----------------------------------------------------------
 0 Migrate   -         Not in progress -                   
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Use `storcli /c0 show` to see the new size of your RAID volume:

```
VD LIST :
=======

--------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC      Size Name 
--------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID5 Optl  RW     Yes     RWBD  -   OFF 10.914 TB data 
--------------------------------------------------------------
                                               ^^^^^^
```

I'm using LVM to manage the disk. `pvscan` shows that the disk size hasn't changed:

```
PV /dev/sdb   VG data   lvm2 [8,19 TiB / 526,00 GiB free]
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Time to reboot (at least I couldn't find a way to make Linux rescan the disk).

At least, `lsblk` now shows the correct disk size:

```
sdb              8:16   0  10,9T  0 disk
                           ^^^^^
```

LVM still can't see it (`pvscan`):

```
PV /dev/sdb   VG data   lvm2 [8,19 TiB / 526,00 GiB free]
```

`pvdisplay` gives more details:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               data
  PV Size               8,19 TiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              2145791
  Free PE               134655
  Allocated PE          2011136
  PV UUID               vM1WQP-CZXu-FrWJ-kRti-hMa2-I1rh-Mga6Xg
```

We can test the next operation before executing it: `pvresize --test -v /dev/sdb`

```
  TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Test mode: Skipping archiving of volume group.
    Resizing volume "/dev/sdb" to 23437770752 sectors.
    Resizing physical volume /dev/sdb from 0 to 2861055 extents.
    Updating physical volume "/dev/sdb"
    Test mode: Skipping backup of volume group.
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
    Test mode: Wiping internal cache
    Wiping internal VG cache
```

`2861055` extents a `4 MiB` translates to `10.91 TiB` (2861055*4096/1024/1024/1024).

Resize the logical volume: `pvresize -v /dev/sdb`

Finally, LVM sees the new capacity:

```
# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               data
  PV Size               10,91 TiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              2861055
  Free PE               849919
  Allocated PE          2011136
  PV UUID               vM1WQP-CZXu-FrWJ-kRti-hMa2-I1rh-Mga6Xg
```

You can now continue to grow the file systems on the volume group.

Comment: A little addition to great Aaron's answer:
You can add disk to array level 0/1/5/6 only. You cannot add disk to array 10 or 50 (look at page 37 [in documentation](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000004186/472fd163/common-storcli-commands#EN-US_TOPIC_0121811691))